# Соответствие хеш-фунций и хеш алгоритмов

Tags: c#

Уточняю вопрос (видимо либо я вас не понял, либо вы меня). Вот части проги

```
private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    m_MethodCombo.Items.AddRange(new[]{"MD5", "SHA1", "MD160"});
}

private void CalcClick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{    
    var method = (string)m_MethodCombo.SelectedItem;    
    HashAlgorithm alg;  
    switch (method)  
    {  
        case "MD5" :  
            alg = MD5.Create();  
            break;  
        case "SHA1" :  
            alg = SHA1.Create();  
            break;  
        case "MD160":  
          alg = RIPEMD160.Create();  
         break;  
        default :  
            throw new ApplicationException("Unknown hash method");  
    }  
    m_OutputBox.Lines =  
        m_InputBox  
            .Lines  
            .Select(line => ComputeHash(alg, line))  
            .ToArray();  
}
```

Видно, что MD160 соответстует хеш алгоритм RIPEMD160. Требуется, чтобы по элементу из выпадающего списка (например MD160) определить название хеш алгоритма (в данном случае RIPEMD160). То есть в моем классе Algorithm будет конструктор, которому будет передан элемент выпадающего списка, а в конструкторе каким-то образом по этому предаваемомму аргументу будет инициализировано поле типа HashAlgorithm моего класса Algorithm. Вопрос заключается в том каким образом это сделать(как я вижу решение: перебрать все HashAlgorithm-ы и с помощью каких-то их методов получать название хеш-функций им соответствующих, но как их пребрать я не знаю и как получить соотвю им названия хеш-функций)?

а так чтоб по всем существующим алгоритмам проходить(не знаю применим ли тут итерартор)и получать названия соответствующих им функций и сравнивать названия этих хеш функций с выбранным элементом из выпадающего списка, т. е. без создания собсбтвенного словаря нельзя обойтись?

Answer (score 2):

походу я вас не примильно понял, но суть словаря остаётся:

допустим вы создаёте класс `Algorithm`

Добавьте в этот класс приватный словарь `Dictionary<string, Func<HashAlgorithm>> d`
и в статическом конструкторе класса или где-нить ещё добавьте в этот словать название алгоритмов и сами методы их создания:

```
d.Add("MD160", RIPEMD160.Create);
d.Add("SHA1", SHA1.Create);
d.Add("MD5", MD5.Create);
```

теперь конструктор:

```
public HashAlgorithm AlgWhatYouNeed {get; private set;}//где-то в классе
...
public Algorithm(string algName)
{
    ...
    AlgWhatYouNeed = d[algName]();//вернёт именно тот Create, который вам нужен
    ...    
}
```

в вашем случае:

```
...
var method = (string)m_MethodCombo.SelectedItem;    
Algorithm alg = new Algorithm(method);  
...
m_OutputBox.Lines =  
    m_InputBox  
        .Lines  
        .Select(line => ComputeHash(alg.AlgWhatYouNeed, line))  
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: а так чтоб по всем существующим алгоритмам проходить(не знаю применим ли тут итерартор)и получать названия соответствующих им функций и сравнивать названия этих хеш функций с выбранным элементом из выпадающего спискаб т. е. без создания собсбтвенного словаря нельзя обойтись?

Comment: Словари достаточно быстродействующие и легковесные объекты, почему нет? Из других вариантов - каким-то изощрённым способом использовать рефлексию, но мороки будет больше...

Comment: А что такое рефлексия?

Comment: Это достаточно сложно:

 - [Отражение (C# и Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173183(v=VS.100).aspx)
 - [Отражение](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx)
 - [Просмотр сведений о типах](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t0cs7xez.aspx)